# Android AlarmService what is scheduled?

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I am referring for example to http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/AlarmService_Service.html

Is there some way to look up what alarms are scheduled in the system?

Just for testing purpose I want to see what is scheduled or if something went wrong.

Thanks,
A.

Answer (score 2):

You can check this by typing at the command line:

```
adb shell dumpsys alarm
```

or just

```
dumpsys alarm
```

from within the adb shell.

Answer (score 0):

I think the alarms are scheduled by putting values in the system database.
You should probably check there.